# I cannot create the encryption function from the decryption function

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

**Last year I solved a easy crypto chall, with a little hindsight, I gave myself the objective of developing the encryption function from the decryption resolution. Here you can see the hint:**

```py
[0, 103, 208, 311, 412, 521, 644, 754, 805, 923, 974, 1088, 1183, 1284, 1402, 1520, 1571, 1685, 1780, 1894, 1942, 1991, 2099, 2194, 2315, 2416, 2530, 2578, 2697, 2807, 2902, 3001, 3115, 3236, 3348, 3464, 3575, 3686, 3734, 3782, 3893, 4004, 4129]
```

**We get an array that looks like it's made up of ord() values.
I spare you the details, I developed this script to solve the challenge:**

```py
x = [0, 103, 208, 311, 412, 521, 644, 754, 805, 923, 974, 1088, 1183, 1284, 1402, 1520, 1571, 1685, 1780, 1894, 1942, 1991, 2099, 2194, 2315, 2416, 2530, 2578, 2697, 2807, 2902, 3001, 3115, 3236, 3348, 3464, 3575, 3686, 3734, 3782, 3893, 4004, 4129]
flag = ''
for i in range(len(x) - 1):
    flag += chr(x[i + 1] - x[i])
print(flag)
# gigem{n3v3r_evv3r_r01l_yer0wn_cryptoo00oo}
```

**With a little thought, I understood that the values ​​were composed in the following way:**

```py
x[2] = ord("g") + ord("i")
x[3] = x[2] + ord("g")
# ...
```

**I tried to recreate the encryption function without success. Anyone know how to do it?**

Comment: Where are you stuck? Looping over the characters of a string?

Comment: Pretty much yes, I understood the logic but I can't seem to apply my idea in a code.

Comment: **A friend founded a solution**

``string = "gigem{n3v3r_evv3r_r01l_yer0wn_cryptoo00oo}"
tmp_output = [0]
for i in range(0, len(string)):
    tmp_output.append(ord(string[i]))

for i in range(1, len(tmp_output)):
    tmp_output[i] = tmp_output[i - 1] + tmp_output[i]

print(tmp_output)
``

Comment: Alright. Now you should be able to get it working using just a single for loop, this is relatively inefficient. For instance: `y = [0]
n = 0
for c in flag:
    n += ord(c)
    y.append(n)
print y
`

Comment: To make it even more efficient you should probably reserve all space for the string / arrays in advance.